# Ansible synchronize and perform action if changed

Tags: ansible, rsync, synchronize

I want to write a playbook to synchronize a source file to a destination host and restart tomcat/apache if the file changed. The documentation on synchronize does not give any example on if this is possible. Can anyone provide some pointers?

Answer (score 1):

If you're only changing one file, you probably want to use [`copy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) instead of `synchronize`.  However, this approach should work either way.

The [handler system](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change) is designed for this sort of thing.  The documentation there provides an example of bouncing memcached after a configuration file change:

> Here’s an example of restarting two services when the contents of a
>   file change, but only if the file changes:
>
> ```
> - name: template configuration file
>   template: src=template.j2 dest=/etc/foo.conf
>   notify:
>      - restart memcached
>      - restart apache
> ```
>
> The things listed in the notify section of a task are called handlers.
>
> Handlers are lists of tasks, not really any different from regular
>   tasks, that are referenced by a globally unique name, and are notified
>   by notifiers. If nothing notifies a handler, it will not run.
>   Regardless of how many tasks notify a handler, it will run only once,
>   after all of the tasks complete in a particular play.
>
> Here’s an example handlers section:
>
> ```
> handlers:
>     - name: restart memcached
>       service: name=memcached state=restarted
>     - name: restart apache
>       service: name=apache state=restarted
> ```